# EQ/EO determination from a functional point sizing perspective

Tags: estimation

I am new to function point(FP) estimation. I am considering the following cases would be considered as External Inquery(EQ)/ External Output(EO) in function point sizing perspective. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Lookup of hard coded country code in a master data entry screen.
2. Master data information maintained by a system
3. lookup of a language code information that is hard coded in the application

Any notification/error message comes out of a system would be considered as External Input(EI) only because EI is maintains round trip in nature (batch job may be the exception) and the notification/error message is a part of the round trip. Is my understanding correct?

For Non functional requirement estimation can we use FP technique or Use case estimation technique?

Comment: Could you  edit the questionand include links to all the acronyms in the post?  EQ/EQ? FP? EI?

Comment: In function point estimation, EQ/EI/EO are very common term. Not sure where is the problem with my question. For example WBS estimation is more commonly used than Work Breakdown Structure estimation. Anyways, I am going to edit my query to replace acronyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Lookup of hard coded country code in a master data entry screen.

In this case, 'lookup' hints that this is an outgoing data, 'hard coded' means it's maintained in an ILF, and since there is no need to change the system's state, or do any calculations this case counts as an **EQ**.

> 2. Master data information maintained by a system

Not sure what 'maintain' here means but 'master data' hints it's just an **ILF**, any method changing, or updating it's state can be an EI/EO though.

> 3. lookup of a language code information that is hard coded in the application

Same as 1. but for a different DET.

> Any notification/error message comes out of a system would be considered as External Input(EI) only because EI is maintains round trip in nature (batch job may be the exception) and the notification/error message is a part of the round trip. Is my understanding correct?

EI means system's state is changed by incoming data coming from an external source, but a notification or error message is an outgoing data and in itself does not change the system's state, so it's more likely an **EQ**.

> For Non functional requirement estimation can we use FP technique or Use case estimation technique?

The name "Non-functional requirement" in this case is misleading. The word 'functional' in light of requirements means functionality from a user perspective. So it is actually the other way around, a non-functional requirement can mean something that the user can **not** interact with. So for these types of requirements, **FP can be used** (and use case techniques not).